# Realm c# : How to add DynamicRealmObject?

Tags: c#, .net, realm

I setup realm (v10.3.0) in c# (VS) and it worked well with classic static objects (inheriting RealmObject). Now I need to create a dynamic object at runtime and thought about sth. like this :

```
RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration(realm_db_name);
config.SchemaVersion = 2;
config.ShouldDeleteIfMigrationNeeded = true;
config.IsDynamic = true;
                
var realm = Realm.GetInstance(config);

realm.Write(() =>
{

                    DynamicRealmObject tmp_obj = realm.DynamicApi.CreateObject("test", "time");

                    for (int min_idx = 0; min_idx < values.Length; min_idx++)
                    {
                        for (int col_idx = 0; col_idx < headers.Length - 1; col_idx++)
                        {
                            tmp_obj.DynamicApi.Set(headers[col_idx], double_values[col_idx,min_idx]);
                        } 

                        realm.Add(tmp_obj);

                    }
});
```

*(headers is a string[] with the header names, double_values is a 2D double array with the values)*

However, I get the following error :

> The class test is not in the limited set of classes for this realm

I also tried to set a different schema version (from 1 to 2), but nothing changed. If I catch the current schema it still holds the old static class I used previously.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed on the MongoDB community forum [here](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-to-add-dynamicrealmobject/119228), unfortunately it's not possible to create a schema programmatically as you want to do. The current dynamic API can only be used to access existing properties.

An alternative to what you're trying to do is probably to use dictionaries:

```
public class HeaderContainer : RealmObject
{
    public IDictionary<string, double> Headers { get; }
}

// Later...

realm.Write(() =>
{

    var container = realm.Add(new HeaderContainer());

    for (int min_idx = 0; min_idx < values.Length; min_idx++)
    {
        for (int col_idx = 0; col_idx < headers.Length - 1; col_idx++)
        {
            container.Headers[headers[col_idx]] = double_values[col_idx,min_idx];
        } 
    }
});
```

Comment: ty! this does it technically, but performancewise it has incredible downsides so it's unfortunately not usable for me. have you tried sth. with dynamic expando objects?

Comment: @c_ph_r the performance is something that the Realm team can take a look at, since they should not be so bad. Regarding dynamic objects, unfortunately it's not something you can use for this, because they have a different use case in mind, even though the naming can sound confusing

Comment: Ok...too bad! I have completed my first round of database benchmark for my usecase and unfortunately realm is not fast enough. I like the handling, it's very intuitive. Hopefully the team is digging a bit into this feature...I will accept your answer as solution anyways..